Upgraded to 24.04 and Encrypted Disk can't be found! "Waiting for encrypted source device". But can access from live install
Well, I thought I'd finally go through the upgrades that my OS kept pestering me about, so I rolled the dice and upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. Then I thought- that worked, why not just do another one?
Well the cryptsetup support is the reason why not!
My laptop, currently on 24.04, fails to get to the password prompt for a luks encrypted device (my root partition). Even more oddly, it will give up and drop to initramfs console, at which point I can run ls /dev, and see my nvme drives are all missing! No wonder they gave up on waiting.
When I use a live thumb drive, I can boot into 24.04, cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mynvmedevice my_device_pseudonim just fine, and I can do anything I need to from there. It's just the initial loading of the machine- it can't find my drives and it gives up.
Any help would be valuable- I need this thing to work!
edit: when working with initramfs, is /dev/nvme* supposed to be there? Some sources say /dev/disk is supposed to be there -I'm not seeing that either :/

I could finally solve this by installing a newer kernel, 6.11, using these instructions -> https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-7-on-ubuntu-heres-how
As I could still access Ubuntu via an old kernel, I installed "Mainline Kernels", selected kernel 6.11 to install and after rebooting, the encrypted disk will be recognized as when in Ubuntu 22.
I can verify the kernel version is 6.11.
I am not sure if there is a way to do this via the Live install.
